# Update the database table and kill the session when the browser closes

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, browser

I need to update the table when the user closes the browser/tab (IE,FF,Chrome,Opera and Safari).

I placed the unload event in MasterPage but the unloading event is firing only the first time. Every other unload event is not firing.

Answer (score 4):

The `beforeunload` event will do what you want, provided the user is still logged in when they close the browser.

**But** you can never be 100% certain of getting the event.

The user may lose their network connection, or crash their computer, etc, which would have the same effect, but you'd never get notified of it.

And because it's a client-side action, it could be intercepted by a malicious script or hacked by the user.

The bottom line is: Do **NOT** rely on this functionality. You need to allow your sessions to die naturally even if are you never notified of the browser being closed. The standard way to do this is with a timeout after a period of inactivity.

And if you're going to allow that anyway, is there any need to actively kill sessions on browser close? You may as well just let them all die naturally with a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(window).bind('beforeunload',function(){
      //do what ever
});
```

Comment: Is it worth noting that this function isn't guaranteed to run and in general, you should avoid trying to rely upon this kind of browser message?